# add time for timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

What is the best method for adding time to a timestamp? 
I have in a database

**2011-10-09 10:29:23**

and I would like add to this 20 days. How can I do that?
I need an example for:

1. 20 hours
2. 20 days

Comment: please point why you weren't able to find the solution to your question in the [gazillion of similar questions on StackOverflow asking how to add time to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+time+php). Also, why is this tagged doctine and symfony when the question doesnt mention anything about those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Date::add](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.add.php) like this:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2011-10-09 10:29:23');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P20D')); //use PT20H for 20 hours
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Use PHP's strtotime function like:

```
$newtimestamp = strtotime("+20 days", $yourtimestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method that works well with Frame is

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time($foo->time_stamp + (24*60*60)));
```

where the number at the end is the old php method `(*days*hours*mins*secs)`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use unix_timestamps, with these you're able to work faster, and if the times were to be displayed to the user, you can use gmdate().